# Unable to edit xml file in powershell -WinRM

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am trying to edit a xml file, when I do it on local machine the code block works perfectly fine

```
[xml]$webXML = Get-Content "C:\Deployment\ABCfolder\web.config"
$mainXML = $WebXml.configuration."system.webServer".httpRedirect
$mainXML.destination -replace "\w.*","http://localhost/ABCname"
$mainXML.Save($webXML)
```

But when I am trying to run it on target servers using winRM, it ends giving error, code below:

```
$server = Get-Content "C:\Files\server.txt"
foreach ($s in $server){
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $s -ThrottleLimit 500
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
[xml]$webXML = Get-Content "C:\Deployment\ABCfolder\web.config"
$mainXML = $WebXml.configuration."system.webServer".httpRedirect
$mainXML.destination -replace "\w.*","http://localhost/ABCname"
$mainXML.Save($webXML)
```

Note: web.config file exist on target server

Error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method 
named 'Save'.
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Save:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
+ PSComputerName        : "SomeRandomIP"
```

Comment: Check .NET version that is installed on the server, and also check Powershell version there. Update both to the same of your PC.

Comment: Something is wrong. ´$mainXml´ is an XmlElement, ´$webXml´ is an XmlDocument. You are telling the element to save the document. You should be telling the document to save itself.

Comment: `$webXML` <> `$mainXML`

Comment: What would be the command in that case, I am confused with the explanation @PalleDue

Comment: Can you use UNC paths to access the xml files? `[xml]$webXML = Get-Content "\\ServerName\C$\Deployment\ABCfolder\web.config"`

Comment: No that is coming from a text file instead i can do $env:COMPUTER_NAME , will that help?

Comment: @v.karbovnichy both are exactly same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the code should be:

1. Read the xml into webXML
2. Change the required node
3. Write webXML back to the file

This code should work:

```
[xml]$webXML = Get-Content "C:\Deployment\ABCfolder\web.config"
$mainXML = $WebXml.configuration."system.webServer".httpRedirect
$mainXML.destination = $mainXML.destination -replace "\w.*","http://localhost/ABCname"
$webXML.Save("C:\Deployment\ABCfolder\web.config")
```